# firepad change height in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, firepad

Firepad documentation says that height is set through css rule:

```
.firepad {
    height: 500px;
}
```

But is it possible to set it in javascript? I want to set the height based on browser window's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

With jQuery:

```
$('.firepad').css('height', '500px');
```

Without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('.firepad').style.height = '500px';
```

If you want to resize both the editor and users list, just replace `.firepad` with `#firepad-container`.

Just do your calculations relative to the browser window's height and use one of these two methods.